# Is it possible to free() or shorten an char array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory-management, static

Is it possible to free() a non dynamically memory?

I have a char array which has a length of 10. I have 4 unwanted zeroes.
Is there a way to trim the last four zeros and shorten the array size? Or is the only way to copy the values to a shorten array

```c
char arr[10]={2,8,2,1,7,1,0,0,0,0}

//NON WORKING CODE! just showing the concept
//The shortArr function dosen't work because i have to pre-declare the size

char * shortArr(char * arr){
 unsigned long len = strlen(arr); 
 static char shortArr[len]; //<--- Variable length array declaration cannot have 'static' storage duration
 memcpy(shortArr, arr, len);
    
 return &shortArr;
};

shortArr();
```

basically what i am doing

```c
unsigned char arr[10]={2,8,2,1,7,1,0,0,0,0}
unsigned char shortArr[strlen(arr)]; 
/*creating a size of 6 by removing the las 0,0,0,0 , 
all do it is quite dangerous to use with strlen since it stops at the first encountering with a zero 
what if the arr had a zero in between the first 7 bytes
arr[10]={2,8,0,1,7,1,0,0,0,0} then only (2,8) would be kept and
and the size would be of 2
*/
memcpy(copyOfArr,arr,sizeof(shortArr)); // copying the bytes from arr to shortArr
```

Comment: `strlen` is intended for string-like arrays and it stops at first 0. To get the size of array use sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]).

Comment: _"Is it possible to `free()` a non dynamically memory?"_  - No, not without having a program with undefined behavior. Why would you want to `free` it though? It free's itself when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @HubertBossy Re:"`sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])`" right but that would just create an array in the same size as arr (10) and shorten i want to create an array with only 6 bytes

Comment: @ Ted Lyngmo i want to shorten the `unsigned char arr[10]` so if i removed the last 4 zeroes by their address then it would be an array of 6 `char arr[6]`

Comment: @dn70a  It sounds like you want to manage the memory consumption manually. You can't go about `free`ing something you didn't `malloc` (or `realloc` etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function that helps to calculate the new length of your intended array. This function would basically count the number of trailing bytes that are equal to `'\0'`.

```
unsigned trimmedlen (unsigned char arr[], unsigned arrlen) {
    unsigned newlen = arrlen;
    for (i = 0; i < arrlen; ++i) {
        if (arr[arrlen - i - 1] != '\0') break;
        --newlen;
    }
    return newlen;
}
```

Now, you can create your new array using VLA (assuming your compiler supports it).

```
unsigned char newarr[trimmedlen(arr, sizeof(arr))];
memcpy(newarr, arr, sizeof(newarr));
```

Comment: This was a great solution on creating a new shorten array, thanks @jxh
didn't know that you can count the number of trailing bytes

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to free() a non dynamically memory?

You should not pass an address not returned by `malloc` or related routines to `free`. The behavior of `free` is specified in C 2018 7.22.3.3. Paragraph 2 says:

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, **if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function**, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, **the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: alright  so basically i have to copy the `arr` in to a shorter array as showing in the second example

Comment: note that you're still not freeing any memory.  you're allocating *more* memory in addition to the unused part of existing memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how short you want your arrays to be, then you can simply do this:

```c
#define ELEM_COUNT 20
char arr[ELEM_COUNT];

#undef ELEM_COUNT
#define ELEM_COUNT 10 //just ignore that in reality, arr has 20 elements
```

And if you don't know it at runtime, then simply store it as a runtime value. Simple!

```c
//with VLAs
size_t size = 20;
char arr[size];
size = 10;
```

Again, simply ignore the fact that the other elements exist. Most of the time, you're accessing the array in loops:

```c
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%c\n", arr[i]);
}
```

So, to reduce an array, all you have to do is reduce the `size` variable. That doesn't waste memory because that's so low in number. Nothing will happen if 10 bytes are wasted. And if it's a large array, don't allocate it on the stack.